# Ghost USB drives don't go away on Windows 10

Tags: windows, usb, bios, malware

Briefly, I have phantom USB drives that showed up a week ago. Rolling back to a "clean" backup that was stored on a disconnected disk didn't solve the problem. I had that previously when I had a major malware infection problem. I would like to
(1) trace the executable/process/registry key that is responsible for emulating these USB drives
(2) Find the host of malware. Does it reside on a Clonezilla image? USB keyboard memory? Protected area of an HDD?

Here are some details

I had a three months long atypical infection of my home computers. It would first reveal it's presence by "ghost usb drives". The number of USB icons increased each time I plugged in and removed a USB drive. Was it counting infected drives? I don't know.
USB drives were plugged in and then ejected. These disks are not accessible, but the icons are still visible in "My Computer"

[image]

Malware would spread by usb drives (possibly usb keyboards) and home network. It penetrates immunodeficient Windows(r)(tm)(c) without a problem and ignores sandbox, antiviruses and firewall. Initially it would prevent antivirus software from running/installing. I tried removing it, but wasn't too successful. Eventually, during this struggle malware got modified/corrupted somehow. It would make bios unbootable. Clearing CMOS (take out battery for at least a day) helped to revive BIOS., but reinfection would happen soon after. Eventually I moved to Linux, formatted all usb drives using Gparted, password protected BIOS of each computer, etc. Recently I've installed Windows 10 on one of the computers. At first, everything went OK, but when I plugged in and ejected my formatted usb in I saw the ghost usb again.

Is it normal to see these ghost drives? How can I find out where the reference to this usb is stored, which module created it, etc? How can I check if the suspicious USB drive is issuing any unusual commands on plug-in? Can files on usb be hidden from Ubuntu if "show hidden files" is enabled?

I repeated steps suggested here: [How to "eject" non-existing USB drive from Windows 7 host?](https://superuser.com/questions/307275/how-to-eject-non-existing-usb-drive-from-windows-7-host) . USBs indeed disapeared. I rebooted Windows. It said "installing updates". After reboot all ghost USBs were back.

Comment: Relevant: [How to "eject" non-existing USB drive from Windows 7 host?](http://superuser.com/q/307275)

Comment: Yes, it is. It talks about the symptom (ghost USB drives). But their workaround doesn't work in my case. Just wanted to show that I did my homework and browsed relevant topics.

Comment: There is an existing question that has numerous answers on how to remove malware.  Have you read that?  **Is it normal to see these ghost drives?** - Nope, it is not normal

Comment: Yes, I've read the question. That is why I cite it in my post. I went through recommended uninstall steps. It didn't help any. Those ghost drives reappear after reboot. Worse so, they appeared after I restored a clean Windows 10 image on my disk. Only the _usb_keyboard_ and the _hdd_ were the same. Image was restored on a separate hardware using while booted under Linux based Clonezilla. My questions are (1) how to trace malware that restores ghost usb? (2) How can it slip through if I took these precautions? (3) What should I do?

Comment: There are numerous answers on how to remove simple malware. These answers all boil down to "if nothing helps - use boot and nuke and then reinstall OS". The problem is that **"reinstall OS" fails to help**. "Roll back using a clean image" fails as well. My question is - where is this malware lurking?

Comment: Are/were these real USB drives, or could they represent an multi-card reader or some other embedded peripheral? This is very similar to how my 15-in-1 USB card reader appears when no storage cards are inserted. In older OS's they disappeared when not used, it later versions of Windows they show up all the time like this.

Answer (score 2):

I talked to the motherboard manufacturer. Surprisingly they were nice enough to help (it took them an hour, but they fixed the problem).

They rebooted computer in safe mode and uninstalled drives. Attempts to uninstall drives in standard mode fails, but in safe mode it works. I don't know what is the Voodoo magic behind it, but attempts to uninstall drives in standard mode fail, but in safe mode it works.

They seemed to do some other steps but they didn't tell me what exactly they are doing. Now it is hard to say if it was a glitch, or a broken malware, that they fully removed or if the malware hid itself. Personally, I would call it a success.

Comment: so, my take home message is - talk to manufacturer. Some of them have nasty "your call is very important for us, so please wait for two hours or hang up now". Others actually do help to resolve the problem. I wish SU allowed opinionated discussions of this kind, but they don't.

Comment: What exactly did they do to "uninstall" the drives? Unfortunately as it stands this doesn't make for a good answer. I know it solved your issue but we need more than "Voodoo magic fixed it".

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly answering the question, but hope I may help some who were as confused as I was by "USB Drive (D:)" showing in my list of drives. In my Windows 10 Dell computer, this is the SD-card slot "designation." Easily checked by inserting an SD card into your slot and see if shows the SC contents. When the SD card is removed, the "extra" USB Drive disappears.

Comment: In my case, my Kingston FCR-HS3 card reader was showing up as 4 phantom drives.