# How can I get my 2nd hard drive (that disappeared from Windows Explorer) back?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-explorer, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

I have a Dell XPS running Windows 8. My C Drive is 120GB SSD, for windows and programs, then I have a 1TB D Drive for my own files. The other day it disappeared from Windows Explorer and I cannot get it back.

It does not show up in Disk Management - but some other random drives do - windows explorer suddenly added a few drives out of nowhere - all labeled "Removable Disk".

[image]

I tried uninstalling them in device manager but they just come back when I refresh

When I go into Disk Management this is what I see:

[image]

I checked in the Bios and it is listed. I'm really hoping my drive has not failed as much of whats on the drive is not backed up.

What should I do? Are there any programs I can run to try to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Have you recently installed any new hardware? Have you run any diagnostics? Have you tried [Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2809468)? How about booting to a Live CD to see if the drive is accessible that way? Please edit your question with these answers, not comments.

Comment: Can you check if the HDD is still getting power and spinning? Have you tried a new SATA cable or SATA port on the mb?

Comment: @CollyFitz you really should edit your first image, your personal email address is clearly visibile

Comment: [How to "eject" non-existing USB drive from Windows 7 host?](http://superuser.com/q/307275)

Comment: Image cropped to remove email address.

Comment: You have the drive linked to your favorites, if you click on that link, what happens?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have tried several different cables etc. Did not try safe mode but I will now. Also a live CD sounds like a good idea. I'm pretty sure it is powering up and spinning but I'll check.